# tic tac toe using functions only. in C++

Tags: c++

I've been asked to make a tic tac toe game, with only 1 human player. using 2d array and functions. I'm not allowed to declare the array or any variable globally.
. The array must be declared within the main function.
. but I see no other way than to declare it globally.
although the game is working properly, I just want help to make this code according to the conditions asked.

```
#include  <iostream>
#include   <cstdlib>
#include    <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

  char choice, O, X;
  char matrix[3][3];  //intitial size matrix declaration    
  //         [y][x] 

void  choice_sign  (void);
void  init_matrix  (void);
void  human_input  (void);
void  count_down   (void);
void  comp_input   (void);
void  disp_matrix  (void);
char  check        (void);

int main(){

start:  
     char win =' ';
     init_matrix();
     choice_sign();


do{

     disp_matrix();                         // displaying the initial empty matrix
     human_input();                         // getting human input
     win = check();            // if the winner is found by check(),by the
```

Comment: Whichever textbook you are using to learn C++, it must be very old, and the shown code is using many obsolete syntaxes, that have not been used in decades. Can you try to find and switch to a more recent C++ textbook?

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing it would be passing the array to your functions calls.

```
int main(){
     char matrix[3][3];
     init_matrix(matrix);
}
```

```
void init_matrix(char matrix[3][3]) {
    //....
}
```

You're effectively passing a pointer to the first element in `matrix`, so changes will be visible across function calls.

However, you can ditch the usage of static arrays and use one of the modern [C++ containers](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) like `std::vector` or `std::array`, and pass it by reference across your function calls:

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
int main(){
    vector<vector<char>> matrix(3, vector<char> (3, ' '));
    // In that case you don't need init_matrix.
    disp_matrix(matrix); 
}
```

```
void disp_matrix(vector<vector<char>>& matrix); { // passing by reference using ampersand `&` operator. 
    //....
}
```

Comment: While this appears to work, there are better ways of passing arrays around than as pointers, so maybe you could show that. In fact, the appropriate data structure to use here would be a `std::vector` or maybe a `std::array`, so you might want to show how to use that as well.

Comment: @cigien Indeed. However, "I'm not allowed to declare the array or any variable globally." with the goto syntax made me think it's some sort of school assignment, which in some cases isn't allowed to use built-in containers, thanks for the tip though, I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer, it's much better now. Note that there are 2 things to consider when answering: one is to help the OP, which the first part of your answer does. The second is to have a useful answer for future visitors, who probably won't have the exact same constraints as the OP. Now the second part of your answer does that as well :)

Comment: @cigien Thanks for the tip, will keep that in mind.

Comment: @a.Li , I can't get that anwer to work. it is showing me same declaration errors.

Comment: @MuhammadOwais What exact errors does it tell you? How did you modify your code?

Comment: @a.Li, sir it shows::  [Error] too many arguments to function 'void disp_matrix()'

Comment: @MuhammadOwais You should modify each of your functions' declarations to take `matrix` as an argument.

Comment: @a.Li , sir, i don't know what i'm doing wrong! :,(

Comment: @Owais The error is pretty much stating that you're passing too many [parameters](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/) to `disp_matrix` (by calling `disp_matrix(matrix)`, while it takes zero parameters in its declaration, you should modify its definition accordingly.